# Excel Error Handling not Stopping Sheet Select Pop-Up

Tags: excel, vba, error-handling, macros, spreadsheet

I've created a function which checks if a sheet exists in an **external** workbook. Code as follows (I've checked this and this works perfectly with other sheets, commenting out the `If` statement that references this stops the error):

```
Function ExtSheetExists(formString) As Boolean
    Dim val As Variant
    On Error Resume Next
    val = ExecuteExcel4Macro(formString)
    ExtSheetExists = (val <> Error(2023))
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

Note: `FormString` is passed as `"'" & wkBookRef1 & firstShtName & "'!" & "R6C12"` where `wkBookRef1` is just the path to the spreadsheet and `firstShtName` is the spreadsheet name that is being looked up.

However later when I go to update the same spreadsheet using the `UpdateLink` method it pops up the Select Sheet dialogue box and thus stops the run of the macro. Does anyone have an inkling as to what is going on here?

The select sheet box is as follows:

[image: Select Sheet Pop Up box]

Comment: what are you passing as formString?

Comment: The sheet you are looking for doesn't exist (in a second code routine?) so it is prompting for you to replace it with a different sheet

Comment: @Nathan_Sav Refer to new note. Thanks.

Comment: @brettdj No sorry. As specified it doesn't exist anywhere else. I think it is just a bug to be honest. Commenting out the `UpdateLink` method works as well as commenting out the if statement that calls the above. I'm just wondering why this case which should be overlooked in the error handling appears again when the file it is referring to is updated with working links. Really weird.

Comment: Where are you using the UpdateLink method though?

Comment: @brettdj I'm using the `UpdateLink` method at the same level as the `If` statement that calls the `ExtSheetExists` function. I've shown through debugging that it had may as well be `If ExtSheetExists(formString) Then Pass End If UpdateLink`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bug. Effectively the `formstring` is run and the message box is suppressed. However it seems that it remains as a latent process in the other spreadsheet. So when it is updated it shows the suppressed message box.